# Getting the author name to appear when using the Vancouver bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am using Vancouver style for bibliography and I want to get author name also. How can I get author name using Vancouver style?

```
\documentclass [44pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage [dvips] {graphicx}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Z}

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\end{document}

@BOOK{Z,
 author={Z, and W},
 title={Growth},
 publisher={Science Press},
 year={1982},
}
```

It gives me "^1" but actually I want "Z^1" (^ denotes superscript).

Comment: Please post a MWE (minimum working example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. It's especially important to do so if you use an unusual document class or citation-related packages. Please also clarify what you  mean by "want to get author name also" -- the `vancouver` style generates authoryear-style citation callouts by default.

Comment: Ok, I am writing in detail. See above.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but with the caveat that you need to enter names in your `.bib` file in the way you want them to appear in the output (which is really not recommended in general).

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Z,
  author={Anthony Adams and Beverly Beach and Carl Clarkson},
  title={Growth},
  publisher={Science Press},
  year={1982},
  address={City}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cases, graphicx}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{usebib}
\newbibfield{author}
\bibinput{\jobname}
\newcommand{\namecite}[1]{\usebibentry{#1}{author}\cite{#1}}

\begin{document}

Regular citation.\cite{Z}

Usebib citation: \namecite{Z}.

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any simple way or command to do it because If I have 20 references then it will be impossible to write \newcommand for each?

Comment: @Ahmed -- Oh, sorry: there was a typo in the `\namecite` macro: it should be `#1` not `Z`, which would mean you can use it the same way you use the `\cite` command (minus the optional argument, which would require a slightly different macro).